# Can I send alert message to MSN messenger or Yahoo! messenger from servers?

Tags: alerts, msn-messenger

There is a server changing a batch to add up data on the date and time, but I want to send the end states (normal end or abnormal termination) of this batch to Yahoo! Messenger or one's ID of the MSN messenger as a message, but a page and the document which I am useful for are not found.

Can I send alert message to MSN messenger or Yahoo! messenger from servers?

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right you want to receive notifications from your server application using msn or yahoo IM protocol. The only way to archieve this is to write an msn or yahoo bot. You can use libpurple for those purposes since it supports msn, yahoo, irc, gtalk and many other protocols. *In my opinion this is an overkill*.

Msn messanger and Yahoo! messanger show notifications about new e-mail messages **so you could send e-mails** from your server application instead of IM messages.

Comment: Got my upvote for the suggestion to use email - a far more widely supported means of communicating, and not much slower than IM these days. Many moons ago I ended a server migration process with a message to the technicians pager. But these days an SMS would be more widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [pymsn](http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/wiki/Pymsn).  You should be able to call that lib from a script to send out alerts.  Someone did something similar and posted the python code over [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-121456.html).  Not sure if it still works. MSN has a habit of updating the MSNP protocol without notice.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a .Net library called [MSMP-Sharp](http://code.google.com/p/msnp-sharp/) that you can use.